# ClickOnce application periodically fails to start

Tags: internet-explorer, .net-framework, clickonce

So, we have a client with a particular LOB application which uses ClickOnce to launch certain features. Every now and then, whenever users try to access these functions (Windows 7, using IE10 or 11, or the latest version of Firefox with the .NET Framework Assistant plugin), they click the link which downloads the manifest, the tab closes, and that's it. No windows with "verifying application requirements" or any of the clickonce download/install process (if you were to try clearing the clickonce cache and rebooting the machine). No indication that the ClickOnce'd app is doing anything. No entries in the event log. Nothing.

We've tried repairs/reinstalls of .NET 4, clearing the ClickOnce cache, browser cookies/cache, etc.

Interestingly enough, if you were to bring a machine that's not joined to the client's domain but connected to the client's network it seems to run just fine. Also, I was unable to reproduce the issue from my network/domain. We've ruled out weird firewall rules, and I've reviewed the GPOs which don't seem to have anything that could possibly affect .NET/ClickOnce.

After getting in touch with the vendor, we took a stab in the dark and added the site to IE's compatibility view mode (although one of the first things the vendor asked is to make sure the site ISN'T in compatibility mode). This workaround worked for about a day. When I chatted with the vendor again, they agreed to escalate this to a software engineer. While I was waiting for the engineers to call me back, the client notified me that the application seemed to work again. However, an hour later, it stopped working again.

Before I call the vendor back, I'd like to do some more diagnosis/investigation on my end to see if perhaps it something odd with our system configuration or if I can give the engineers more info to go on. Can anybody point me in the right direction to see what else could be going on that could cause this?

Comment: Before I go down a road that I want to avoid, what operating system is the user using, the use of IE 10 and IE11 indicates either Windows 8.1 or Windows 7

Comment: Windows 7. Should've mentioned that in the OP.